# How do I take photos of myself with iPhoto?

Tags: macos, mac, iphoto

I would like to make pictures from my self with iPhoto, and I do not know how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iPhoto is photo management software.  Perhaps what you want is [Photo Booth](http://www.apple.com/macosx/what-is-macosx/photo-booth.html), which uses your computer's camera to take pictures.  Once you've taken the pictures, you can import them into iPhoto.

Photo Booth should be in your Applications folder.